# jQuery, variable maths in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, variables

I'm trying to make a form that will work out how much something will cost based on the options selected. I have managed to make it work successfully for 3 options however I can't figure out how to make it create the subtotal, this subtotal should add the variables "vpageprice" and "vmediaprice" and be displayed inside the cell with the id "st". Below is my code and heres a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw555000/Q3eKA/).

HTML

```
<div style="margin:auto;text-align:center;" id="form">
    <table width="300" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr><th scope="col">Element</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Price</th></tr>

        <tr><td>Media</td><td>
                <select id="media">
                    <option value="0">None</option>
                    <option value="5">Audio</option>
                    <option value="10">Video</option>
                    <option value="12">Both</option>
                </select></td>
            <td id="mp"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Page Style</td><td>
                <select id="pagestyle">
                    <option value="10">Seperate</option>
                    <option value="5">Content Change</option>
                </select></td>
            <td id="ps"></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Pages</td><td>
                <select id="pages">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select></td>
            <td id="pp"></td></tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2">Total</td><td id="st"></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    function mediaprice() {
        var vmediaprice = $("#media").val();
        $("#mp" ).html("£"+vmediaprice);
    }
    $("#form").change(mediaprice);
    mediaprice();    
    function pagestyleprice() {
        var vpagestyleprice = $("#pagestyle").val();
        $("#ps" ).html("£"+vpagestyleprice+" per page");
    }
    $("#form").change(pagestyleprice);
    pagestyleprice();    
    function pageprice() {
        var vpageprice = ($("#pages").val())*($("#pagestyle").val());
        $("#pp" ).html("£"+vpageprice);
    }
    $("#form").change(pageprice);
    pageprice();    
});
```

I hope someone can help me resolve this issue, if anyone has a better/easier way to make this form I will change what I have. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very very simple solution:

```
$("#form").change(function() {
    $("#st").text("$" + (pageprice()+mediaprice()));
}).change();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3eKA/7/)

Comment: This does what I want but as already stated its pagestyle*pageprice not plus so the equation comes out wrong. If you can make the equation come out right I'll accept your answer as its simpler than others.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but I have another issue with the code, the total price doesnt appear until an option is clicked, can you remedy that please?

Answer (score 2):

here is solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/Q3eKA/1/

```
function pageprice() {
  //your stuff
  getTotal();

}
function getTotal(){
    var total = parseInt($('#pages').val(),10) * parseInt($('#pagestyle').val(),10)
        total += parseInt( $('#media').val(),10);
    $('#st').text('£' + total);
}
```

Comment: This works well thank you. Question: why does parseInt have 10 at the end?

Comment: it's radix, it's have to be defined to avoid possible problems with parsing number.

Comment: for example, parseInt("0700") //448 or parseInt("0700",10) //700

Comment: Ahh so this is to make it decimal as appose to an alternative number system like binary or hexidecimal? thank you for your answer and helping me understand the code behind it :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function mediaprice() {
  var vmediaprice = $("#media").val();
  $("#mp" ).html("£"+vmediaprice);
  return parseFloat(vmediaprice);
}
function pageprice() {
  var vpageprice = ($("#pages").val())*($("#pagestyle").val());
  $("#pp" ).html("£"+vpageprice);
  return parseFloat(vpageprice);
}    
function pagestyleprice() {
  var vpagestyleprice = $("#pagestyle").val();
  $("#ps" ).html("£"+vpagestyleprice+" per page");
  return parseFloat(vpagestyleprice);
}

function updateAll(){
    var total = mediaprice() + pageprice(); //Order here affects
    $("#st" ).html("£"+total);
}    

$("#form").change(updateAll);
updateAll();

});
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/Q3eKA/4/

**EDIT** Thinking better of your logic, this would be the `updateAll` method:

```
 function updateAll(){
    pagestyleprice();
    var total = mediaprice() + pageprice(); //Order here affects
    $("#st" ).html("£"+total);
 }
```

Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/Q3eKA/6/

Cheers

Comment: Pagestyleprice is times pageprice not plus.

Comment: So that bug is in your original code also. I just used your code

Comment: "var vpageprice = ($("#pages").val())*($("#pagestyle").val());" theres definitely a times in my code.

Comment: hehe look your pageprice function and mine, they both multiply

Comment: I mean in the "function updateAll" it adds them together in the total where it should times them. if you can make the equation work with the times then I'll accept your answer as it eliminates some of my previous code.